# Python join - how to join a data in loop?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I join a data below,

```
# Convert Spark DataFrame to Pandas
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
print pandas_df

   age     name
0  NaN  Michael
1   30     Andy
2   19   Justin
```

My current attempt,

```
persons = ""

for index, row in pandas_df.iterrows():
    persons += str(row['name']) + ", " + str(row['age']) + "/ "
    print row['name'], row['age']

print persons
```

Result,

```
Michael, nan/ Andy, 30.0/ Justin, 19.0/
```

But I am after (no slash at the end),

```
Michael, nan/ Andy, 30.0/ Justin, 19.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do

```
persons = []
str_pearsons=""

for index, row in pandas_df.iterrows():
    persons.append( str(row['name']) + ", " + str(row['age']))
str_pearsons="/ ".join(persons)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :D

Comment: @teelou happy to help

Comment: @teelou you could accept the answer which you feel is right or post below their answer that it did not solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep your method of looping through each , then you can simply remove the last `/` by doing `rstrip()` on it to strip from the right side. Example -

```
persons = ""

for index, row in pandas_df.iterrows():
    persons += str(row['name']) + ", " + str(row['age']) + "/ "
    print row['name'], row['age']

person = person.rstrip("/ ")
print persons
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> person = "Michael, nan/ Andy, 30.0/ Justin, 19.0/ "
>>> person = person.rstrip('/ ')
>>> person
'Michael, nan/ Andy, 30.0/ Justin, 19.0'
```

---

But if you really do not want the `print row['name'], row['age']` inside the loop, then you can convert this into a generator function and let `str.join()` handle what you want. Example -

```
person = "/".join(",".join([str(row['name']), str(row['age'])]) for _, row in pandas_df.iterrows())
```

Comment: I think `rstrip` would be a better choice over `rsplit` here

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily in a one liner that will be vectorised:

```
In [10]:
'/ '.join(df['name'] + ', ' + df['age'].astype(str))

Out[10]:
'Michael, nan/ Andy, 30.0/ Justin, 19.0'
```